# Lotus Notes JavaScript Get user info

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

User visit web site on it's own PC and javaScript creates NotesSession.

```
var ns = new ActiveXObject("Lotus.NotesSession");
ns.Initialize(pass); // user password
```

I would like to get user info such as name and corporate phone number after successful session initialize. For message like "Hello `%username%`, your phone is `%number%`" I know way to get info about specific user from Domino server if I know name or something else, but in this case I'm stuck a bit.
If I try to use GetDatabase InternetExplorer hangs.

```
var db = ns.GetDatabase("", "names.nsf");
```

Get internet address will be good too

Comment: You may check out Session class http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_10_NOTES_CLASSES_ATOZ_JAVA.html

Comment: I can get username now by ns.CommonUserName, but still have no idea how to get phone, use loop to find phone by username from server database is not an option because of it take much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering why you're doing this in JavaScript on the browser side instead of doing it on the server side, because this will only work for users who have a Notes client installed and configured correctly. However, if this is really the way you want to go...

The only information that you get automatically with the session is the user's name (in a few different formats). If you want anything else, you have to look up the user information on the server.

You can use

```
var nd = ns.getDirectory()
var userinfo = NotesDirectory.LookupNames("$Users",ns.UserName, fieldsArray)
```

to get more info.

Note that there are several phone number fields in the Domino Directory and depending on your organization's policy and procedures they may not all be filled in. You'll need to look up the item names (e.g., "OfficePhoneNumber", "PhoneNumber", "CellPhoneNumber" .. there are others) and put the ones that you want to retrieve into the fieldsArray that you pass to LookupNames. You'll get the result back as a [NotesDirectoryNavigator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDIRECTORYNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html) object, and you can use that object's methods and properties to get the value.

Comment: I'm doing it with JS because server belong to other department of organization and located even in other region, so because of it I cannot modify anything on server side, and this is the only way how it can be done. I needed field OfficePhoneNumber, your answer solved my problem. And authorize with lotus client made to restrict access to the users account from any place except users workplace. .

Comment: Office number is a key to get info about users phone calls from my automatic telephone system server, so web page will be small members area with info about calls

Comment: It's not necessarily the only way it can be done. For example, if your web server authenticates users and runs Java, you could write code that runs on the web server to connect to the Domino server and do the lookup using NCSO.jar. Or from just about any langauge on your web server you could use the Domino REST API or perhaps even use LDAP. Yes, your Domino server would have to be set up to support those methods, but it might already be set up for one of them. In any case, doing it from the browser does work, but its likely to be a little slower.